# How to translate dynamic attributes "[attr]" in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, attributes, internationalization, angular6

Translating attributes does work very well, as described in Angular's [i18n guide](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#translate-attributes):

```
<button type="button" i18n-title title="open menu">
```

---

Now I want to toggle the `title`-attribute based on the state of component:

```
<button type="button" i18n-title [title]="active ? 'close menu' : 'open menu'">
```

The value is toggled correctly. Unfortunately no translation is extracted in this case.

---

Even without any further logic, no translation gets extracted:

```
<button type="button" i18n-title [title]="'open menu'">
```

---

How can I solve this? I don't want to duplicate the button.

Comment: I think your'e looking for select among alternative text https://angular.io/guide/i18n#select-among-alternative-text-messages. If not, you're trying change by code. In this case your'e can take severals alternative. The simpliers is read from a .json file, others can be my "translationComponent" e.g. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppkadc?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftranslation.component.ts or use ngx-transtale

Comment: Unfortunately ICU doesn't work on attributes. It seems that the feature request is blocked as well: [i18n Plans: Allow ICU messages in attributes](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16477). So there's no way to get this work, without ngx-translate or some hacks? @Eliseo

Comment: It's a little shit, but you can have two buttons and a *ngIf